# Show/Hide wordpress submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am having some difficulty swapping the behaviour of my Wordpress menu. I am looking for it show when clicked and not when hovering:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
        <li>
            <br />
        <form method="get" id="search_form" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>">
            <input type="text" class="text searchForm" name="s" value="Search" >
        </form>
    </ul>
</nav>

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".sub-menu").hide();
    $(".current_page_item .sub-menu").show();
    $("li.menu-item").click(function () { // mouse CLICK instead of hover
        $(".sub-menu").hide(); // First hide any open menu items
        $(this).find(".sub-menu").show(); // display child
    });
});
```

When I change it to toggle it kills off the other links in the menu. I am not sure what the issue is here...

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle or other demonstration?

Comment: It is quite tricky because its a custom Wordpress template I have created, so what happens is it works fine when you hover over the header of the menu to show the sub menu item underneath, yet if you switch it to toggle it toggles perfectly well but kills off the other nav items.

Comment: I don't say any errors inside your code. There must me something related to the dom structure. Without it I can't say much.

Comment: That is ok, thank you for offering to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use the jQuery click function, instead of hover. Also you'll have to make sure the `<a>` tag doesn't work, by disabling the default behaviour of the hyperlink.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".sub-menu").hide();
    $(".current_page_item .sub-menu").show();
    $("li.menu-item").click(function () { // mouse CLICK instead of hover
        // Only prevent the click on the topmost buttons
        if ($('.sub-menu', this).length >=1) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        $(".sub-menu").hide(); // First hide any open menu items
        $(this).find(".sub-menu").show(); // display child
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: so that is almost right, it now shows and quickly hides. what could be the reason for that?

Comment: I would like the menu to stay open unless you click on another item in the menu and then it closes.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your requested behaviour.

Comment: Very odd, it still does the same thing, is it because the link is also loading a new page? So the link I click on opens the menu and then loads a new page

Comment: I presume then, that there's probably a <a> tag in the li.menu-item aswell? If so, the event bubbles to the a and subsequently activates the link it's assigned. In other words: you should probably implement something like event.preventDefault(); Let me know if this works.

Comment: Let me update my question, you can see my full code if that works for you?

Comment: Edited my answer to fix the issue.

Comment: Updated it, so topmost link only is disabled.

Comment: Hmmm, its strange because even your update is cancelling out the other menu links still... the actual function of the showing and hiding works but the links are dead.

Comment: Doesn't close on second click. Is it possible to? @JensKooij